# nested for loops inverted half pyramid

Tags: java

for a school project, I am trying to make an inverted half pyramid

my code is currently this

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
            int rows = 5;
            for(int i = rows; i >= 1; --i) {
                for(int j = 1; j <= i; ++j) {
                    System.out.print(j + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
    }
```

with this output:

```
12345
1234
123
12
1
```

desired output:

```
 54321
 =4321
 ==321
 ===21
 ====1
```

Comment: Your inner loop (using `j`) counts from 1 to `i`, change that to go from `i` to 1 if you want to change the order.

Comment: That is not the output of your current code, since your code prints a space after every number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update (based on the updated requirement):

You need a loop to print the `=` equal to (`rows` - `row number`) times.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int rows = 5;
        for (int i = rows; i >= 1; --i) {
            for (int j = i; j < rows; j++) {
                System.out.print("=");
            }
            for (int j = i; j >= 1; --j) {
                System.out.print(j);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
54321
=4321
==321
===21
====1
```

### Original answer:

Your inner loop should be

```
for (int j = i; j >= 1; --j)
```

i.e. for each row, it should start with the row number (i.e. `i`) and go down up to `1`.

Comment: how would I alter it to produce the new desired output?

Comment: @MentalOverload - I've posted an update based on your new requirement.

Answer (score 0):

It is straight forward you will have to change to things: your inner loop and you will have to move println statement inside the loop

//code

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int rows = 5;
    for (int i = rows; i >= 1; --i){
        for(int j = i; j >= 1; --j)
            System.out.print(j + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```